# How is routing done in react-router-dom version 6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having issues with routing in `react-router-dom` v6. My code is as follows :

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header';
import Home from './Home';
import { BrowserRouter as  Router, Routes, Link } from "react-router-dom";



function App() {
  return (
    //BEM
    <Router>
        <div className="app">
          <Routes>

          <Route path="/" element={[<Header />, <Home />]} />
          
          </Routes>
        </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Nothing gets rendered.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You should be giving a single component to `element` property. Assuming that you wanna `Header` on top of every route, try with this :

```js
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header';
import Home from './Home';
import { BrowserRouter as  Router, Routes, Link } from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
  return (
    //BEM
    <Router>
        <div className="app">
          <Header />
          <Routes>
             <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

If you want to have Header only on path `/`, a cleaner way is to put it inside `Home`. Otherwise you could do it like so:

```js
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import './App.css';
import Header from './Header';
import Home from './Home';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
        <div className="app">
          <Routes>
              <Route path="/" element={<><Header/><Home/></>} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap multiple elements in Fragment

```
<Route path="/" element={<><Header/><Home/></>}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping them in fragment?

```
<Route path="/" element={<><Header/><Home/></>}/>
```